# create the element_id-value using for loop in html/css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to create a element_id-value pair and then dump that data into a file.
Please help me out to create a function to create element_id-value using for loop.

```
<body>
<form class="box1" >

<fieldset>

<label class="my_text4" >firstelement</label>
<input class="left_padd" type="text"  id="firstelement" name="basic_attributes"  value="firstvalue"  />
<p/>

<label class="my_text4" >secondelement</label> 
<input  class="left_padd" type="text"  id="secondelement" name="basic_attributes" value="secondvalue">
<p/>

<label class="my_text4" >thirdelenent</label>
<select id="thirdelement" name="thirdvalue" >
<option value="option1" selected>option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
<p/>

<div> <input  class="button1" type="button" id="bt" value="create variable_value file" onclick="saveFile()" />  </div>
</form>
</body>

<script>

let saveFile = () => {

// Get the data from each element on the form.
var elements_names = ["basic_attributes"]

for(var j=0; i<elements_names.length; j++) 
{
var inputs = document.getElementsByName(elements_names[j])

for(var k=0; i<elements_names.length; k++) 
{
var id1 = inputs[0].getAttribute( 'id' );
var value1 = inputs[0].getAttribute( 'value' );                         
}
//document.write(id1 + " " + value1 + " " + inputs.length)
}

</script>
```

I am trying to create a element_id-value pair and then dump that data into a file.
Please help me out to create function to have element_id-value using for loop.

Comment: yes. from the html form, i want the values and then write those values to a file. so i am looking to get all those values along with their id using a for loop.

Comment: html, java and javascript? are you sure about Java?
the title is not clear at all, can you improve it?
can you avoid repetition of text? you asked your question twice.
at last, try to create yourself the function, then ask what is not working.

Comment: updated the heading. Function is already present which is not working

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late reply. Thank you for the solution!!

Comment: @vineetjain [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @vineet jain, if you found the answer useful, can you please upv and mark it as the the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<form class="box1" >

<fieldset>

<label class="my_text4">First Element</label>
<input class="left_padd" type="text"  id="firstelement" name="basic_attributes"  value="firstvalue"  />
<br /><br />

<label class="my_text4" >Second Element</label> 
<input  class="left_padd" type="text"  id="secondelement" name="basic_attributes" value="secondvalue">
<br /><br />

<label class="my_text4" >Third Element</label>
<select id="thirdelement" name="thirdvalue">
    <option value="option1" selected>option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
<br /><br />

<div>
<input  class="button1" type="button" id="bt" value="create_variable_value_file" onclick="saveFile()" /> 
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>

<div id ="demo"></div>

<script>
function saveFile() {
    var elements_names = ["basic_attributes"];
    var j, k;
    var id1, value1;

    document.getElementById("demo"). innerHTML = "";

    for(j=0; j < elements_names.length; j++)  {
    var inputs = 
    document.getElementsByName(elements_names[j]);

    for(k=0; k < inputs.length; k++)  {
        id1 = inputs[k].getAttribute("id");
        value1 = inputs[k].value; 
        document.getElementById("demo"). innerHTML += id1 + " " + value1 + " " + inputs.length + "<br>";          
    }
}
}
</script>
```